# Shared bus, issue with timing and priority (in VHDL)

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I have multiple FIFOs (multiple buses) and their output data will be sent to only one bus. This data (from different FIFOs) will be available at the same time, or with difference of a few cycles. I have two problems:

1. For example if FIFO2 is ready first, the rd_en2 is sent to '1', and the data from FIFO2 is sent to the bus, after a few clock cycles the FIFO1 is ready, but the bus is still "occupied", and it should maintain occupied with data from FIFO2 until it appears "0000". How will the bus know that next in line is FIFO1, and how to activate the rd_en1 only when the data from FIFO2 appears with all '0'?
2. If the FIFO1 and FIFO2 are ready at the same time, how to choose between them (I was thinking in applying a round-robin arbiter, but don't know how). If I choose, for example FIFO1 to go first, how to put FIFO2 next in the bus?

The next image is a scheme of what I have right now.[image: Block Scheme]

If someone could help me guiding me in the right direction, I'm missing something in my approach and I don't know what.
Thanks in advance.

The vhdl code I wrote:

```vhdl
entity Arbiter is

 Port    ( 
           clk       : in  std_logic;                       -- 200 MHz clock
           datain1   : in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);  -- ADC1 FIFO Output
           datain2   : in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);  -- ADC2 FIFO Output
           rd_en1    : out std_logic;                       -- rd_en1 signal
           rd_en2    : out std_logic                        -- rd_en2 signal);
end Arbiter;

architecture Behavioral of Arbiter is

    signal s_cnt1       : std_logic_vector (9   downto 0)   := "0000000000";
    signal s_cnt2       : std_logic_vector (9   downto 0)   := "0000000000"; 
    signal s_count      : std_logic_vector (3   downto 0)   := "0000";          
   
begin  -- arch

   count <= s_count;
      
main_proc : process(datain1(15), datain2(15))
    begin
        if datain1(15) = '1' then
            s_count <= "0000";
        elsif datain1(15) = '0' then
            s_count <= "0001";
        end if;

        if datain2(15) = '1' then
            s_count <= "0001";
        elsif datain2(15) = '0' then
            s_count <= "0000"; 
        end if;
    end process;

clock_proc : process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if datain1(15) = '0' then
                s_cnt1 <= s_cnt1 + 1;
            else
                s_cnt1 <= (others => '0');
            end if;

            if datain2(15) = '0' then
                s_cnt2 <= s_cnt2 + 1 ;
            else
                s_cnt2 <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process clock_proc; 
    
count_proc : process(s_count)
    begin
        if s_count = "0000" then
            rd_en1  <= '1';
            rd_en2  <= '0';
        elsif s_count = "0001" then
            rd_en2  <= '1';
            rd_en1  <= '0';
        else
            rd_en1  <= '0';
            rd_en2  <= '0';
        end if;
    end process count_proc;

end Behavioral;
```

To simplify, fisrt I am experimenting with only two FIFOs, the MSB from datain1(15)='1', datain2(15)='1' indicates the start of the frame, and datain1(15)='0', datain2(15)='0' indicates the frame is finished. The signal s_count is responsible to jump from one FIFO to the other, as I don't know how to implement a decent arbiter, I am always doing it the same order, first FIFO1 and then FIFO2, then FIFO1 and next FIFO2, and so on, so there wouldn't any starvation.

The folowing images are the results of simulation:
[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your FIFO, there are two ways these can be implemented:

- output data is always valid, `read_enable` allows the FIFO to advance in the next cycle
- output data is valid only in the cycle after `read_enable` was asserted.

The difference between those is one cycle delay, and this delay is the time your arbiter is missing.

The arbiter needs to establish which source to enable in the next cycle, the input to this decision is the busy state (between start-of-packet and end-of-packet), the current selection and a set of "request" signals from sources that are ready to send.

With the "always-valid" FIFO, the start-of-packet can be used as the request signal, but with the delayed FIFO, you need a request signal that appears at least one cycle before the data. Your options there are to use the "fifo not empty" signal, and to add a register stage that delays the data by one cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Simon!
I don't know if I quite understood your answer, but from what I understood, my problem it's not in the FIFO, the block is well implemented, it's only enabling the output (rd_en).  Assuming my FIFOs always have valid data, I only want to read from the FIFO a certain number of cycles, this number is definied by the number of cycles the datain1(15) = '1', and the same is valid to FIFO2. 
I want to read first FIFO1 and stop reading when the datain1(15) = '0', and in the next cycle start reading from FIFO2 until datain2(15) = '0', and back again to read FIFO1.

Comment: From both simulation images, don't know if it is understandable, I want dataout1 to start with ("8000") and finish with ("0000") and only after the ("0000") of FIFO1 start the rd_en2 from FIFO2, that will start ("8000") and finish with ("0000") and only then activate, again, rd_en1.

Comment: @Katrina10, the thing is that there are two possible FIFO implementations, and your arbiter needs to know which. Assuming you have the "always-valid" implementation, you want to set `rd_en` only when you see the top bit set on the FIFO output, and in the idle state, none of the `rd_en` would be set.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Simon! I will try with a FSM to have different states, and in idle none of the rd_en is '1'.